# why after compress a tar file to gz,the file name have been change?

Tags: php, compression, gzip

```
private function compress($compressPath)
{
    $tarDir= $compressPath . ".tar";
    $c = new PharData($tarDir);
    \FileHandle::getAllFiles($compressPath, $filesList);
    foreach ($filesList as $file) {
        $c->addFile($file, basename($file));
    }
    $c->compress(Phar::GZ);
    unset($c);
    FileHandle::deleteDir($compressPath);
    unlink($tarDir);
}
```

Hi.
My tar name is such as "Name1.0.1pro.tar". After compress tar file to gz, the gz filename have been change to "Name1.tar.gz".How can I keep the name is the same?

Comment: The dots may be confusing. Try with hyphen character "-"

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki,thank you.I know the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/ext/phar/phar.c) of Phar, it seems they find the filename by searching for the first occurrence of '.' (a dot). Than split on that to obtain the extension and the filename. *(note: i did not read the full 3621 lines of code)*

So, I would suggest you use php [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to rename the file after it has been created.